# Synonyms in text classification

Tags: nlp, text-mining, text-classification

I am trying to perform some text classifications using python.

I figured that I should convert all the strings into lists of words and exclude the stopwords. I also performed stemming. However, I was wondering if grouping synonyms together would enhance performance? And if so, how to program this? Also I was thinking of normalizing the word counts with tf.idf?

Example:
"The student eats his vegetables.", and
"The student consumes his vegetables." should become the same list:
["student", "eat", "his", "vegetable"] (or with consume instead of eat)